# Cmake 'find_libraries', NAMES keyword not working

Tags: c++, cmake

First time user here so pleasy be gentle.
I have problem with linking libraries using cmake.
I'am working on part of the bigger project. Each part has its own build system, but can use libraries from other parts. Eample project tree:

```
+-- Project
|   +-- Part1
|       +-- Lib1
|           +-- libLib1.a
|       +-- Lib2
|           +-- libLib2.a
|   +-- Part2
|       +-- Lib3
|           +-- libLib3.a
|       +-- Lib4
|           +-- libLib4.a
|   +-- MyPart
|       +-- Lib5
|           +-- libLib5.a
|           +-- Lib1.cpp
|           +-- CMakeLists.txt
|       +-- main.cpp
|       +-- CMakeLists.txt
```

I try to link my part MyPart, with libraries Lib1, Lib2, Lib4, Lib5.

With Lib5 there is no problem as it is build with the same cmake tree.
But how to link outside libraries?
I choose to use **find_library** to obtain path to each of the other needed library, for example:

```
find_library(LIB1_LIBRARY
             NAMES Lib1
             PATH ../Part1/Lib1/)
```

And then use **target_link_libraries**. Unfortunetly as a result of **find_library** i get **LIB1_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND**.
But if keyword NAMES is to be removed, all start working as expected.

What is wrong here? And also is there better strategy for linking libraries from outside of my build system tree.

thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you using `find_library` when your libraries are located within your project directory structure? Do you somewhat expect said libraries to be present in default locations on your system so that the installed versions will be used instead of the local ones?

Comment: I follow some rules from stackoverflow. Read somwhere that `find_library` is a best way to get absolute path to library. And no, the local ones will be used. I know that simply using `target_link_libraries` pointing to given libraries works also. But the problem that irks me is why NAMES keyword do not work?

Comment: Please note that the `PATH` argument is not recognized by `find_library`. As per the documentation, it should be `PATHS` instead.

Comment: And all is good now :D thx man PATHS did it. And as for the using of `find_library` any suggestions? Is using simply `target_link_libraries` with  direct path better?

Comment: the project setup is a bit suspect. You normally either want dependent libraries to be in the build tree or in some pre-requisites install path. The you would use `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<location of dependencies>` and `find_package()`

Comment: I admit that project setup is ... ugly and suffers from chaotic project management. Thats why I want to my part be written as best as i could (also regarding build system). Any tutorials for setting libraries to be used with `find_package()`?

Comment: @BudziwojMan best thing to do is to examine `find*.cmake` files installed with cmake and analyze how they work.